# not able to see the Picture on web page

Tags: html, angularjs, gruntjs, mean-stack

I have deployed my build code on the server. the build was done using the grunt build.
There are a few places where i need to show the pictures. but these pictures are not visible.

```js
<img src=https://agileprojectdash.com/client/app/images/Maturity_Curve2.PNG class=img-rounded width=100% height=90%>
```

the above tag is part of minified file below tag.  "angular.module("DashboardApp").run(["$templateCache",function(a){a.put("app/pages/admin/admin.html",'') "

the image is located at = client/app/images
and the html file is in client location.

Comment: You're missing a lot of `"`?